# Layered UIViewControllers?

Tags: iphone

Maybe this isn't the best way to approach this...

Working on an app that could use two simultaneous UIViewControllers, layered, one on top of each other.

The rear UIViewController would run some background animation and respond to certain touch events through the front UIViewController.

The front UIViewController runs a game.  Half a dozen UIImageViews with buttons on top.

The reason I want to separate them is that the code for each UIViewController is unique and somewhat complex.  I really don't want to mix two separate state machines and related methods and properties into a single UIViewController.  Doing that for a demo and it is a mess.

What would be the right approach, if not the layered UIViewController idea?

Comment: how would it be to use two UIView sub class on one viewController only .You can separate every thing that you want ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does sound like you want a single `UIViewController` class that manages its views via multiple custom `UIView` sub-classes.

Comment: I am trying different approaches.  This might end-up becoming an OpenGL ES application.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Remember `UIViewController` is "the fundamental view-management model for iOS applications", whether your views are OpenGL or not. Good luck.